Bounding the Coefficients of a Polynomial Written as the Sum of Powers of Linear Forms
Background:
Consider the space of forms (i.e., homogeneous polynomials) of degree $d$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$ in $n$ variables. Call this space $\mathfrak{F}(n,d)$.
It is well known, (for example, see Białynicki-Birula and Schinzel) that any $F(x_1,\dots,x_n) \in \mathfrak{F}(n,d)$ can be written as a superposition of $d$th powers of linear forms, i.e.,
$$\begin{align}
F(x_1,\dots,x_n) &= \sum_{\mu=1}^m L_\mu(x_1,\dots,x_n)^d\\
&= \sum_{\mu=1}^m \left( b_{\mu,1} x_1 + \dots b_{\mu,n} x_n \right)^d\\
&= \sum_{\mu=1}^m \left(\mathbf{b}_\mu \cdot \mathbf{x}\right)^d
\end{align}$$
where $m \le {n+d-2 \choose d-1}$ and $\mathbf{b}_\mu \in \mathbb{C}^n$.
Problem:
Suppose that we are guaranteed that $|F(\mathbf{x})| \le 1$ for all $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{D}^n$ where $\mathbb{D}$ is the closed unit complex disk. The goal is to obtain a bound on the one-norm of the vectors $||\mathbf{b}_\nu ||_1$.
If you would like, you could even assume that the $F \in \mathbb{R}$ whenever $\mathbf{x} \in [-1,1]^n$.
Conjecture: $ ||\mathbf{b}_\nu||_1 \le 2$ for all $1 \le \nu \le m$.

Attempt:
I've been running around in circles trying to obtain a bound on the vectors $\mathbf{b}_\nu$, or else find a counter-example, but to no avail.
Hölder's inequalities seem completely useless, as they give us upper-bounds on $|F|$ rather than lower bounds.
Fix $1 \le \nu \le m$.
The most fruitful direction I found as to define a vector $\mathbf{a} \in \mathbb{C}^n$ such that $b_{\nu,i} a_i = |b_{\nu}|$ (i.e., $a_i$ is equal to the complex conjugate of the phase of $b_{\nu,i}$). Then,
$$\begin{align}
F(\mathbf{a}) &= \left( \mathbf{b}_\nu \cdot \mathbf{a} \right)^d + \sum_{\mu \ne \nu} \left( \mathbf{b}_\mu \cdot \mathbf{a} \right)^d\\
&= \left( \sum_{i=1}^n |b_{\nu,1}|  \right)^d + \sum_{\mu \ne \nu} \left( \mathbf{b}_\mu \cdot \mathbf{a} \right)^d\\
\Rightarrow |F(\mathbf{a})| &= \left| ||\mathbf{b}_\nu||_1^d + \sum_{\mu \ne \nu} \left( \mathbf{b}_\mu \cdot \mathbf{a} \right)^d \right| \le 1
\end{align}$$
but then I get stuck, as each $\left( \mathbf{b}_\mu \cdot \mathbf{a} \right)^d$ could possibly be negative.

Examples:
Here are some examples of polynomials written as superpositions of powers of linear forms. In the case of single-variable polynomials, it is useful to consider the Chebyshev polynomials $T_d(x)$, as they automatically satisfy that $|F| \le 1$ condition. Note that not all of these are homogeneous, but I'm trying to use the homogeneous result to prove a more general result, as any degree $d$ polynomial $p(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ can be made homogeneous by defining $x_0^d p(x_1/x_0,\dots,x_n/x_0)$, applying the result, then setting $x_0 = 1$.
$$\begin{align}
xy &= \left(\frac{1}{2} x + \frac{1}{2} y \right)^2 + \left(\frac{i}{2} x - \frac{i}{2} y \right)^2\\
T_4(x) = 1 - 8 x^2 + 8 x^4 &= 4\left(x + i/\sqrt{6}\right)^4 + 4\left(x - i/\sqrt{6}\right)^4 + 7/9\\
T_5(x) = 5 x - 20 x^3 + 16 x^5 &= \frac{75}{4}x^5+\frac{1}{8} (x-2)^5-\frac{3}{2} (x-1)^5-\frac{3}{2} (x+1)^5+\frac{1}{8} (x+2)^5
\end{align}$$

Any counterexamples or suggestions on ways to move forward would be highly appreciated!

Also posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/480383/bounding-the-coefficients-of-a-polynomial-written-as-the-sum-of-powers-of-linear
